# How to allocate 100 bytes of memory

Tags: c++

I come across this question in an interview. I answered

```
char *p = new char[100];
```

which is wrong according to interviewer.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way, and what exactly interviewer was expecting?

Comment: "How to assign..." what value? assignment always comes with assigning a certain value. Or do you mean allocation? What you're showing is allocating an array of 100 characters (which usually is 100 bytes large), but not assigning this area any value

Comment: `memcpy(dest, src, 100);`

Comment: he probably meant a `memset` call, `memset(v, 0, 100)`.

Comment: @keltar the c++ way to do this would be `std::fill`

Comment: @nyarlathotep, Sorry, it was allocate. i done the edits.

Comment: I think this question is impossible to answer with anything except a wild guess... Can you provide any more context, any extra requirements?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct. However, it requires manual memory management and is thus error-prone. A more C++-y way would be

```
std::vector<char> buffer(100);
```

Or indeed, if the number 100 is a compile-time constant:

```
std::array<char, 100> buffer;
// or
char buffer[100];
```

Finally, if we are really interested in low-level memory management, here is another way:

```
std::allocator<char> alloc;
char* buffer = alloc.allocate(100);
```

Comment: Question was using new.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Doesn't look like that, the only *"new"* in question is in your one line of code.

Comment: Can I `delete` the pointer returned from `allocate`?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen No. You need to call `deallocate` *with the same allocator*.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what sits in his head, he might not know that `char` is guaranteed to have size equal to 1 in C++ (**§5.3.3/1**), and was expecting something like:

```
void* mem = malloc(100);
```

Still, in C++ `vector` would probably be preferred.

Or maybe he didn't want you to use dynamic allocation at all?

Comment: Interview questions are always difficult; without context almost any single line can mean multiple things.

Comment: @PP. yes, but if the interviewer said it's *wrong*, he might have meant *improper behavior*, not merely a style/idiom issue.